# How to calculate a Kernel/Matrix efficiently

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matrix, optimization, vectorization

```
import numpy as np

solution_point_count = 150
impedance_datapoint_count = 134 

impedance_frequency = np.logspace(np.log10(100000), np.log10(0.0199), impedance_datapoint_count)
solution_frequency_logspace = np.logspace(np.log10(100000), np.log10(0.06), solution_point_count)
    
# Initializing zeros matrix to store results     
Z_RC = np.zeros((impedance_datapoint_count,solution_point_count))

#Constructing Debye Model for RC Kernel
#Debye Model: Z_RC = 1/(1 + iω*) where ω = 2πf and  = RC = 1/(2πf)

for n in range(solution_point_count):
    for m in range(impedance_datapoint_count):
        Equation = 1/(1+1j*impedance frequency[m]/solution_frequency_logspace[n])
            Z_RC[m,n] = np.real(Equation) # Extracting real part only
```

While this works to create the kernel Z_RC, it is very slow and probably inefficient. Is there a more efficient way to do this? Perhaps with vectorization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for n in range(solution_point_count):
    for m in range(impedance_datapoint_count):
        Equation = 1/(1+1j*impedance frequency[m]/solution_frequency_logspace[n])
            Z_RC[m,n] = np.real(Equation) # Extracting real part only
```

should be calculable with 'broadcasted' arrays.  Without testing I'd suggest

```
Z_RC = (1 / (1 +1j * impedance_frequency[:,None] / 
    solution_frequency_logspace)).real
```

This divides (m,1) array by a (n,) to produce a (m,n)

Comment: I've added your solution to the `perfplot` benchmark.

Comment: Thank you! With your version of broadcasted arrays I was able to go from ~45ms to ~1ms each time this matrix is made

Answer (score 0):

The straightforward solution would be using [numba](/questions/tagged/numba):

```py
from numba import njit

@njit
def calculate_numba(impedance_frequency, solution_frequency_logspace):
    solution_point_count = len(solution_frequency_logspace)
    impedance_datapoint_count = len(impedance_frequency)

    Z_RC = np.empty((impedance_datapoint_count, solution_point_count))

    for n in range(solution_point_count):
        for m in range(impedance_datapoint_count):
            Equation = 1 / (
                1 + 1j * impedance_frequency[m] / solution_frequency_logspace[n]
            )
            Z_RC[m, n] = np.real(Equation)  # Extracting real part only

    return Z_RC
```

---

Benchmark using `perfplot`:

```py
import numpy as np
import perfplot
from numba import njit


def generate_impedance_frequency(solution_point_count, impedance_datapoint_count):
    impedance_frequency = np.logspace(
        np.log10(100000), np.log10(0.0199), impedance_datapoint_count
    )
    solution_frequency_logspace = np.logspace(
        np.log10(100000), np.log10(0.06), solution_point_count
    )
    return impedance_frequency, solution_frequency_logspace


def calculate_normal(impedance_frequency, solution_frequency_logspace):
    solution_point_count = len(solution_frequency_logspace)
    impedance_datapoint_count = len(impedance_frequency)

    Z_RC = np.empty((impedance_datapoint_count, solution_point_count))

    for n in range(solution_point_count):
        for m in range(impedance_datapoint_count):
            Equation = 1 / (
                1 + 1j * impedance_frequency[m] / solution_frequency_logspace[n]
            )
            Z_RC[m, n] = np.real(Equation)  # Extracting real part only

    return Z_RC


def calculate_broadcast(impedance_frequency, solution_frequency_logspace):
    Z_RC = (
        1 / (1 + 1j * impedance_frequency[:, None] / solution_frequency_logspace)
    ).real
    return Z_RC


@njit
def calculate_numba(impedance_frequency, solution_frequency_logspace):
    solution_point_count = len(solution_frequency_logspace)
    impedance_datapoint_count = len(impedance_frequency)

    Z_RC = np.empty((impedance_datapoint_count, solution_point_count))

    for n in range(solution_point_count):
        for m in range(impedance_datapoint_count):
            Equation = 1 / (
                1 + 1j * impedance_frequency[m] / solution_frequency_logspace[n]
            )
            Z_RC[m, n] = np.real(Equation)  # Extracting real part only

    return Z_RC


# check if the calculation is the same:

solution_point_count = 150
impedance_datapoint_count = 134

impedance_frequency, solution_frequency_logspace = generate_impedance_frequency(
    solution_point_count, impedance_datapoint_count
)

out1 = calculate_normal(impedance_frequency, solution_frequency_logspace)
out2 = calculate_numba(impedance_frequency, solution_frequency_logspace)
out3 = calculate_broadcast(impedance_frequency, solution_frequency_logspace)

assert np.allclose(out1, out2) and np.allclose(out1, out3)


perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: generate_impedance_frequency(n, n),
    kernels=[
        calculate_normal,
        calculate_numba,
        calculate_broadcast,
    ],
    labels=["normal", "numba", "broadcast"],
    n_range=[10, 20, 50, 100, 150, 200, 500],
    xlabel="N x N",
    logx=True,
    logy=True,
)
```

Result:

[image]

---

EDIT: Added @hpaulj *broadcast* solution.

Comment: For whatever reason, when I use numba the execution speed goes from 45ms to about 1000ms. Nevertheless, thank you for answering the question and including hpaulj's answer to your benchmark plot!

Comment: @impedance_gatto Probably you see compilation time. When you run the function for first time `numba` compiles the function, which takes time. When you run the function for second time, you should see faster times (function is already compiled)